# algorithm to compute waiting time for FCFS scheduling in python

Tags: python, algorithm, methods

Consider the following code that takes input processes and their arrival times and sort them according to FCFS algorithm, so i've been thinking about algorithms to compute avg waiting time but all is false so any suggestions ?

Processes = input("   Enter the  processes times & arrival times separated by a comma: ")

```
    BurstTimes = Processes[::2]
    ArrivalTimes = Processes[1::2]
    print '   Burst Times:', BurstTimes, '\n', '   Arrival Times', ArrivalTimes,'\n',
    list1, list2 =  BurstTimes, ArrivalTimes
    indices1 = range(len(list1))
    indices1.sort(key=lambda x: list1[x])
    list1 = map(lambda i: list1[i], indices1)
    print 'The Processes executed in this order: ', list1 
    Wt_Time = 0
```

the code for calculating the total time:

print 'The Processes executed in this order: ', list1

```
    process_queue = []
    total_wtime = 0
    for i in range(len(list2)):
        process_queue[i].append(int(list1[i])
        total_wtime += process_queue[i][1]
```

and it gives error at the last line

Comment: "all is false" - what does that mean? What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: the ouput give wrong values

Comment: What values? What values are you expecting? And *where is the code*?

Comment: waitingTime = startTime - arrivalTime

turnaroundTime = burstTime + waitingTime = finishTime- arrivalTime

Comment: Please edit the question to add the code, properly formatted, and provide the two other pieces of information I have asked for.

Comment: Provide sample input, tell us what your program outputs, and tell us what the expected output is.

Comment: i cannt upload pic of console due to my low reputations

Comment: @user3547642 we don't want a picture, we want numbers! And please revisit your code formatting.

Comment: there was a shortcut that formats the code can u tell me what it was?

Comment: @GarethBale I don't know quite what you mean, but it you highlight the code and click the `{}` button that does it.

Answer (score 0):

> process_queue[i].append(int(list1[i])

you are appending the i'th element of list1 to the process_queue list , You should note that list1[i] is not a list but an integer . and in next line you are trying to access

> total_wtime += process_queue[i][1]

1st element of the process_queue[i] but it is not a 2d array

> > total_wtime += process_queue[i]

should work .

Answer (score 0):

```
# Author:Geraldo Braho
process_queue = []
total_wtime = 0
n = int(raw_input('Enter the total numbers of processes: '))
for i in xrange(n):
    process_queue.append([])#append a list object to the list
    process_queue[i].append(raw_input('Enter process name: '))
    process_queue[i].append(int(raw_input('Enter process arrival Time : ')))
    total_wtime += process_queue[i][1]
    process_queue[i].append(int(raw_input('Enter Process CPU bustTime : ')))
    print ''

process_queue.sort(key = lambda process_queue:process_queue[1])

print 'ProcessName\tArrivalTime\tBurstTime'
for i in xrange(n):
    print process_queue[i][0],'\t\t',process_queue[i][1],'\t\t',process_queue[i][2]

print 'Total waiting time: ',total_wtime
print 'Average waiting time: ',(total_wtime/n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Concept: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-fcfs-scheduling-set-2-processes-different-arrival-time/

```
processes = [
    {"pid": "P0", "burst_time": 5, "arrival_time": 0, "service_time": None, "waiting_time": None},
    {"pid": "P1", "burst_time": 3, "arrival_time": 1, "service_time": None, "waiting_time": None},
    {"pid": "P2", "burst_time": 8, "arrival_time": 2, "service_time": None, "waiting_time": None},
    {"pid": "P3", "burst_time": 6, "arrival_time": 3, "service_time": None, "waiting_time": None}
]

# No waiting time for first process
processes[0]["waiting_time"] = 0
# Service_time of the first process is it's arrival time
processes[0]["service_time"] = processes[0]["arrival_time"]

for i in range(1, len(processes)):
    # Case where process comes when processor is in idle state
    if processes[i]["arrival_time"] > (processes[i - 1]["service_time"] + processes[i - 1]["burst_time"]):
        processes[i]["service_time"] = processes[i]["arrival_time"]
    else:
        processes[i]["service_time"] = processes[i - 1]["service_time"] + processes[i - 1]["burst_time"]

    processes[i]["waiting_time"] = processes[i]["service_time"] - processes[i]["arrival_time"]

total_waiting_time = 0

for process in processes:
    total_waiting_time += process["waiting_time"]

avg_waiting_time = total_waiting_time / len(processes)

print("Average Waiting Time:", avg_waiting_time)
```